# Why `A & a = a` is valid?

Tags: c++, constructor, reference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
  Base() : m_member1(1) {}

  Base(const Base & other) 
  { 
    assert(this != &other);   // this should trigger
    m_member1 = other.m_member1; 
  }

  int m_member1;
};

struct Derived
{
  Derived(Base & base) : m_base(m_base) {} // m_base(base)

  Base & m_base;
};

void main()
{
  Base base;

  Derived derived(base);

  cout << derived.m_base.m_member1 << endl; // crashes here
}
```

The above example is a synthesized version of a mistyped constructor.
I used reference at the class member `Derived::m_base` because I wanted to make sure that the member will be initialized as the constructor had called.
One problem is that nor GCC nor MSVC gives me a warning at `m_base(m_base)`. But the more serious for me is that the assert finds everything fine and the application crashes later (sometimes far away from the mistake). Question: Is there any way to indicate such mistakes?

Answer (score 3):

The assert doesn't trigger because you're not creating an instance of `Base` in the call `m_base(m_base)`. This is just initializing the reference `Base& m_base`. If you actually want to call the copy constructor, then declare `m_base` as a value `Base m_base`.

Also, one way to catch that kind of mistake is to have your compiler warn about unused parameters. The gcc flag is `-Wunused-parameter`, or `-Wextra -Wunused`.

Comment: normally A & a = a; gives me the mentioned compiler warning. But in the example this warning does not come. The answer is correct about the lack of calling the copy constructor. But my problem is the dangling reference.

Comment: @psag, the warning I suggested will be raised in this case since you're not using the parameter `Base& base`. But you're right, I can't seem to get gcc to warn directly about `m_base(m_base)` (whether or not it's a reference).

Comment: Here's a bug report discussing self-initialization (`int i = i`): http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34772. But it seems to focus on warning when you use the variable, not when you initialize it with itself, which seems like where it *should* be warning you.

Comment: I can imagine a scenario when self-initialization should be OK. Maybe someone wants to call the operator= for some reason in this weird way. But a reference should always refers to somewhere with size. (At least as long as the referred object is not deleted)